# Pulldowns from waist

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, exercise-technique

A few years ago I was doing seated lat pulldowns. The gym instructor came by and suggested an additional exercise. Using the same machine I stood up and started with my upper arms by my sides and my forearms parallel to the floor. I then pulled down, using forearms only, and back to start. I then did the reps that fitted with the rest of my routine. It seems like a good exercise but:
a) Do you know what it is called please?
b) Can you please tell me which muscles it works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a cable tricep pushdown.

[image]

It works your triceps in isolation, since this is the muscle that is used to extend your elbow joint. (Whereas the bicep is used to close the elbow joint.)